# Problem with converting octave code to python/pandas - wrong signal processing due to incorrect float64 values

Tags: python, pandas

I did not find all anwsers regarding my problem or each of questions deal with just part of it. After few days of trying I decided to post a question.

I am doing biomechanical research involving computing maximum velocity of a kicks. There are three kicks captured in each file (simple finding maximum value wont do). I need to find maxium values of those kicks. With some help I manage to do it using matlab/octave but I for future work I decided to stick with python for data processing.

The point is that I have time,x,y,z data of a specific marker and I need to compute its velocity for each registered frame and pick maximum velocity from each kick.

This is a code in octave:

```
pkg load signal

txyz=importdata('295ltoe.txt',',',8); % read the text file 
txyz=txyz.data; % all data in array time,x,y,z 
dxyz=diff(txyz); % first differences of all columns 
vxyz=dxyz(:,2:end)./dxyz(:,1)/1000; % compute velocity components 
v=sqrt(sum(vxyz.^2,2)); % and the total velocity 

[pks,locs]=findpeaks(v,'minpeakheight',6 )
```

I tried to convert it to pandas with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
data1 = pd.read_csv("B0264_dollyo_air_P_T01 rtoe.txt") #examle of txt 
imported from c3d file

df = data1.diff()
dfx = (df['X'] /1000) / df['T']
dfy = (df['Y'] /1000) / df['T']
dfz = (df['Z'] /1000) / df['T']
dfx1 = dfx**2
dfy1 = dfy**2
dfz1 = dfz**2
v = (dfx1 + dfy1 + dfz1)**1/2
peaks, _ = find_peaks(v, height=6)
plt.plot(v)
plt.plot(peaks, v[peaks], "x")
plt.show()
```

The problem is that velocity gets values like that:

```
0                NaN
1       6.450000e-07
2       8.237500e-07
3       1.159062e-06
4       1.250312e-06
5       1.657500e-06
```

instead of normal correct values it gives me values more than 60. I am attaching plots that I recived vs excel correct polot (excel computing is time consuming due to constant copypasting).

[image]
[image]

My total aim is to get 3 max peaks and 3 min peaks to compute time of kick execution, but I do not know how to obtain it.

For know, if anyone is willing to help me I can provide files I have used.

Comment: Please remove the octave tag